# How to run a CasperJS script every hour automatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a CasperJS code that executes some tasks on my website. I want the code to run every hour!

For the moment being, the code is running locally and manually (using `casperjs cas.js`) every time. Now I want:

1. To make it run every hour automatically
2. To deploy it somewhere (e.g. Heroku)

I could achieve the first objective by making a Node server that runs the command `casperjs casper/cas.js` every hour (using `setInterval` function). However, I couldn't deploy it on Heroku since it supports only one type of code (Node.js). The `cas.js` script is written with CasperJS, so it couldn't been executed!

What is the best way to achieve these two goals?

Comment: Why not deploy the script at a linux server and run it via cron scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you are on Linux...

**1. The most elegant solution is to use a cron job**, as suggested by [Vaviloff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2715393/vaviloff).

If you want to execute your **CasperJS** script every hour, you can edit your crontab with `crontab -e` and then add the following entry:

```
0 * * * * PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/casperjs /absolute/path/to/your/casper/script.js 2>&1
```

Some remarks:

- `0` means "0 minute". It is required here, otherwise your script will run every minute.
- Since CasperJS depends on **PhantomJS**, you have to specify the path to the PhantomJS command using the proper environment variable (`PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE`).
- Make sure PhantomJS & CasperJS paths are `/usr/local/bin/phantomjs` and `/usr/local/bin/casperjs` respectively, using `which` (`which phantomjs` & `which casperjs`).
- Do not forget to write the **absolute path** to your own CasperJS script.
- `2>&1` redirects **stderr** to **stdout**.

**2. Use [SpookyJS](https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS) if you want to run CasperJS scripts with Node.js.**

```
npm i spooky
```